# Kick command discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i am having a few difficulties getting my kick command to only allow people with the permission node `KICK_MEMBERS` to kick people. currently i have the bot in a state where anyone and everyone is allowed to kick the following is my code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (user) {
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      if (member) {
        member
          .kick('Optional reason that will display in the audit logs')
          .then(() => {
            message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {
        message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
      }
    } else {
      message.reply("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
    }
};

  module.exports.help = {
    name: "kick"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`GuildMember#hasPermission` returns a boolean of whether a user has a specified permission or not. We can use it to declare if the user has the `KICK_MEMBERS` permission.

#### Final Code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS', { checkAdmin: true, checkOwner: true })) return message.reply('You cannot use this command!') 
  // I like to have it so people with the administrator permission can use it regardless.
  const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (user) {
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      if (member) {
        member
          .kick('Optional reason that will display in the audit logs')
          .then(() => {
            message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {
        message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
      }
    } else {
      message.reply("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
    }
};

module.exports.help = {
  name: "kick"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped alot!